# How to access Button programatically if the button is inside using C#

Tags: wpf, listview, button, tabcontrol

I have few questions as I am usign XAML for the first time.

1. How do I use the button (BrowseButton) to browse a folder in Harddrive ?
   In this case as the button is inside
2. Can I use  the way I have shown below?
   Actually first dockpanel will hold the image and some label and the other dockpanel will have tabcontrol in it.
3. If I have a tabcontrol, How can I add a listview which can increase the tabs during runtime.. and the listview should be available in the runtime also.
   How to add a close("X") mark on the top of the tab to close the button

probably I asked a lot of questions, sorry :(

Please help

```
<Grid>
        <DockPanel>
            <StackPanel>
                <Image Name="imgClientPhoto" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="auto" Height="auto" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Margin="0" 
                       Source="D:ehtmp_top_left.gif" MinWidth="450" MinHeight="100" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">

                </Image>

                 <Button x:Name="BrowseButton" Margin="0,13.638,30,14.362" Content="Browse" Click="BrowseButton_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="111" />
                            <TextBox x:Name="txtBxBrowseTB" Margin="46,10,146,10" Text="TextBox" TextWrapping="Wrap" TextChanged="BrowseTB_TextChanged"></TextBox>
                            <Label HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="-14,22,0,10" Name="label1" Width="69.75" FontSize="13" VerticalContentAlignment="Top" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center">Path:</Label>
                        </Grid>
                    </GroupBox>
                </Grid>

            </StackPanel>

        </DockPanel>
        <DockPanel>
            <StackPanel Margin="0,158,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="330" Height="557.5" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                <TextBox Height="50" Name="textBox1" Width="240" Margin="0,35,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
                <ListBox Height="470" Name="listBox1" Width="332" Background="LightGray" Margin="0,0,0,0" BorderBrush="IndianRed" BorderThickness="3" />
            </StackPanel>
            <TabControl Height="234" Name="tabControl1" Width="1035" Margin="0,0,0,0">
                <TabItem Header="tabItem1" Name="tabItem1">
                    <Grid Height="144" />
                </TabItem>
            </TabControl>
        </DockPanel>
    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

1) The browse code should be something like this:

```
private void BrowseButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog browse = new System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog();
    browse.RootFolder= Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments;
    browse.SelectedPath = "C:\\InitalFolder\\SomeFolder";
    if (browse.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
    {
        txtBxBrowseTB.Text = browse.SelectedPath;
    }
}
```

2) I have tried to simplify the xaml. Does this look like something you could go with?:

```
<Grid>
    <Image Name="imgClientPhoto" Margin="0" Height="262" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" ></Image>
    <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Stretch" >
        <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Top" Orientation="Horizontal" Height="30">
            <Button Name="BrowseButton" Content="Browse" Click="BrowseButton_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="111" />
            <Label Name="label1" Width="69.75" FontSize="13" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right">Path:</Label>
            <TextBox Name="txtBxBrowseTB" Width="200" Text="TextBox" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" TextChanged="BrowseTB_TextChanged"></TextBox>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <TextBox Height="50" Name="textBox1"  />
                <ListBox Height="470" Name="listBox1" Background="LightGray" Margin="0,0,0,0" BorderBrush="IndianRed" BorderThickness="3" MouseLeftButtonUp="listBox1_MouseLeftButtonUp">
                    <ListBoxItem>User1</ListBoxItem>
                    <ListBoxItem>User2</ListBoxItem>
                    <ListBoxItem>User3</ListBoxItem>
                    <ListBoxItem>User4</ListBoxItem>
                </ListBox>
            </StackPanel>
            <TabControl Name="tabControl1" />
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

You can also have a close button in the tab item Header. As many of the content properties in xaml controls, the content can actually be controls, and not necessary just a text.

```
        <TabControl Name="tabControl1"  >
            <TabItem Name="tabItem1" >
                <TabItem.Header>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Label>TabHeader1</Label>
                        <Button Height="20" Width="20" FontWeight="Bold" Click="CloseTabButton_Click">X</Button>
                    </StackPanel>
                </TabItem.Header>
                <Grid Height="144">
                    <ListView />
                </Grid>
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
```

3) Here is how you would add the tabs in C# dynamically:

```
private void listBox1_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    //Get selected item
    ListBoxItem item = (ListBoxItem)listBox1.SelectedItem;
    string itemText = item.Content.ToString();

    //Check if item is already added
    foreach (TabItem tItem in tabControl1.Items)
    {
        if ((string)tItem.Tag == itemText)
        {
            //Item already added, just activate the tab
            tabControl1.SelectedItem = tItem;
            return;
        }
    }

    //Build new tab item
    TabItem tabItem = new TabItem();
    tabItem.Tag = itemText;

    //First build the Header content
    Label label = new Label();
    Button button = new Button();
    label.Content = itemText;
    button.Content = "X";
    button.Height = 20;
    button.Width = 20;
    button.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
    button.Click += CloseTabButton_Click; //Attach the event click method
    button.Tag = tabItem; //Reference to the tab item to close in CloseTabButton_Click
    StackPanel panel = new StackPanel();
    panel.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;
    panel.Children.Add(label);
    panel.Children.Add(button);
    tabItem.Header = panel;

    //Then build the actual tab content
    //If you need only the ListView in here, you don't need a grid
    ListView listView = new ListView();
    //TODO: Populate the listView with what you need
    tabItem.Content = listView;

    //Add the finished tabItem to your TabControl
    tabControl1.Items.Add(tabItem);
    tabControl1.SelectedItem = tabItem; //Activate the tab
}

private void CloseTabButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //The tab item was set to button.Tag when it was added
    Button button = (Button)sender;
    TabItem tabItem = (TabItem)button.Tag;
    if (tabItem != null)
    {
        button.Click -= CloseTabButton_Click; //Detach event handler to prevent memory leak
        tabControl1.Items.Remove(tabItem);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I am using C#.
(the subject has C# listed :))
I am verynew to this WPF and XAML, so couldnt sort out how to work on this.
Please help

Comment: Hi Awe,
Sorry if i confused you. My req: if I hav 4 users in the list box and if I click on them, then a new tab should be opened. so, for every newtab, the Listview should be added(this Listview is common for all tabs).a "X" mark on the tab to close the tab also. 
So, the Listview will contain 1.Workbook, 2. Desc.. and so on as columns.

Hope I made some sense.
I can explain if u need it.
Thanks
Ramm

Comment: Hi Dreas,
I edited the question.
1. A basic ques:The way of accessing a button will remain same, if the button is present inside <stackpanel> which inturn is present in <Grid> ?? I mean <Grid><StackPanel><Button>Browse</Button></StackPanel></Grid

Comment: The easiest way to access the button is to set Name on the button. Then you can access it directly in code by using the name.

Comment: I consider my answer finished now, based on how I understand your questions. Do you understand these consepts now?

Comment: Hi Dreas, Thanks a lot.. i got confidence to work on xaml.. thanks a lot for the help.. 
Will ask u help if I am struck in some implementation :) :)

Thanks
Ramm

Comment: Just to tell you that it is **awe** that has given you this answer... Another user, Dreas, just did a small bug fix in the C# code at one point, which is probably what you have picked up...

Comment: oh sorry awe.. a thumbs up for ur answer.. 
I thought ur original name is dreas and ur display name is awe..
:) :).. anyways thanks a lot for the answer